# VS Annoying CSS Alert

Tags: visual-studio

```
<link href="http://www.../default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Could not edit 'http://...' because it is not in the Web site.**

I get this error box every five minutes, how do I get it to stop telling me this?

Comment: Can you add why you are using a css from another website? Might be easier to solve the problem outright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link runat="server" id="defaultCss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and on your code behind

```
defaultCss.attributes.add("href","http://www..../default.css");
```

if your css is in your website then you can use

```
ResolveUrl("~/default.css")
```

to get the url

or probably best practice is to add it to your app theme folder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx and then not only will it be automatically added but you'll get intellisense

Comment: defaultCss.Attributes.Add("href","http://www..../default.css"); // works (Case Sensitive)

Answer (score 2):

Well, seems like it's because you're including an href that points to a URL, instead of a relative web path.

Instead of

```
<link href="http://www.mysite.com/styles/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

use

```
<link href="/styles/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Also, make sure your closing

```
/>
```

is valid in terms of your Doctype.

Comment: I'd like to keep it the way it is and just get rid of that constant error message. o_0 Is that possible?